# iphone choice for a developer

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been developing some iOs stuff using the simulator and a real iPad. Now I think I really need an iPhone but I am not really into taking it around, my Nokia is just perfect for my needs.
I was wondering: isn't it better for a developer to get a second hand 3g - 3gs instead of an expensive 4/4s so that the apps can be tried with the lowest-end device? what do you think? Am I losing something with this choice besides the possibility of trying it with a newer retina screen?

---

Edit: I don't want to use it as a phone, it's just for the development. I would like to know if from a developer point of view all the versions 3g up are the same, besides screen resolution. In this case, since I'd do audio application, I would have the possibility of testing the slowest hardware, that can be a good choice for me. Thank you!

Comment: This is a very subjective question. It just depends on too many personal things for us to give you a good answer. Personally, I have an iPhone 4S for everyday use, and an iPhone 3G, iPod 2G and iPod 4G for testing.

Comment: maybe after the edit the questions are less subjective!

Comment: If you think for long term iPhone 3G, 3GS are soon going to be outdated. And same for iPhone 4 in a year and half. So Why purchasing those soon to be outdated device? What about latest features those are coming in latest iPhones? How will you test them? Do remember majority of the users are going to be using latest devices. So I would recommend latest device for testing.

Comment: I understand, but if I try a cpu intensive application, then I guess the lowest supported model would be the best choice for development. I know that the best would be having a 3g and a 4s, but I would like to decide for one and only. This toys are expensive if you don't plan to use them in real life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be a mistake to get a 3Gs to target at this point, given that probably by the end of the year the 4 or 4s will take the place of the 3Gs as the low-end device.

Targeting the 3Gs for testing makes sense for perhaps another year or two, if you don't mind upgrading past that point.

One other consideration is that if you are really going after augmented reality, you'll probably want to use some of the hardware advances from the iPhone 4 on, so from that standpoint also an iPhone 4 makes more sense as a test device than a 3Gs.

Comment: ok so I would be safe for 2-3 years with an iPhone 4.. I will get that then.. thank you guys for the opinions, and sorry for the non-programming OT :)

Comment: With all due respect, I would like to say this answer is not entirely correct. I think we all agree that a 3G would really be too dated. But a 3GS, apart from not offering a retina display, is technically super close to the 4 (CPU, GPU, RAM), hence I do not see a mandatory reason for choosing one over the other. I guess your point is Apple's iOS update strategy and the possibility of leaving the 3GS behind very soon. If that is the case, then I tend to agree a bit more to this answer - minding that they did the same with the 2G and the 3G which also were technically almost identical.

Answer (score 4):

Are you developing phone specific functionality? If not then you could use an iPod Touch. The current generation has a camera and the retina screen; last generation has the lower resolution screen and might not have the camera.

Comment: Yes, I would also like to try augmented reality so I need 3g, thank you!